# Specflow step definition failing due to cannot set void as implicit type variable

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I am new to specflow C# so apologies if I have made some basic programming mistakes.

I have a list of actions in my specflow that contain the following:

```
When I enter in invalid email Test.TestEmail.plc for Email address field
    And I enter in invalid email Test.TestEmail.plc for Confirm email address field 

...

    And I enter in correct email Test@TestEmail.plc for Email address field

    And I enter in non matching email Test@TestEmail.co.uk for Confirm email address field

...

And I enter in matching email address Test@TestEmail.plc for Confirm email address field
```

The only changes between the steps are:
- the type of email (invalid, matching, non matching)
- the email addresses
- the text bar theyre entered in to

So I thought lets paramertised them but I am unable to get it working so I wanted some help on what is the correct way to tackle this.

First of all in the code I try to and find an element by it's locator and set a string type for the email text:

```
public void GetFieldAndEnterText(By fieldElement, string fieldText) =>
    _driver.FindElement(fieldElement).SendKeys(fieldText);
```

In the step definition I have it set like this:

```
 [When(@"I enter in (.*) email (.*) for (.*) field")]
    public void WhenIEnterInInvalidEmailForField(string emailType, string fieldText, By fieldElement)
    {
        var email = _payment.GetFieldAndEnterText(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.EmailAddressField);
        var confirmEmail = _payment.GetFieldAndEnterText(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.ConfirmEmailAddressField);

        if (fieldElement.Equals("Email Address"))
        {
            return email;
        }else if (fieldElement.Equals("Confirm Email Address"))
        {
            return confirmEmail;
        }

            _payment.GetFieldAndEnterText(fieldElement, fieldText);
    }
```

You can see I am trying to pass three different parameters. The first one doesn't matter in terms of code, it's just so I can use this step definition over and over again.

The second parameter is the email which is mentioned in the specflow to know which email to type.

The last parameter is the locator where based on if the filed is email or confirm email field, it will try to find the element.

However in the step definition I am receiving errors for email and confirmemail variables as cannot set void to implicit type and the return would not work as it's a void type.

What is the correct way to tackle this?

Comment: Try to put single quotes around you parameters (and adjust your regex). So it would be "And I enter in 'correct' email 'Test@TestEmail.plc' for 'Email address' field" and [When(@"I enter in '(.*)' email '(.*)' for '(.*)' field")]

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. You mentioned your are new to C#, I would recommend you spend some time doing some C# programming tutorials, reading some good books, etc.

`GetFieldAndEnterText()` has a `void` return... that means it doesn't return anything but you are assigning its return to `email` and `confirmEmail` in `WhenIEnterInInvalidEmailForField()`. That's the reason for the error. How to fix it is unclear because I don't understand what your `WhenIEnterInInvalidEmailForField()` method is supposed to be doing. Please describe in words what you expect your `WhenIEnterInInvalidEmailForField()` to do and return, if anything.

`GetFieldAndEnterText()` takes two parameters but you are only passing in one in the `email` and `confirmEmail` lines.

You are comparing a `By` class to a `string` in your `if` and `else if`.

You are using a `return` twice in `WhenIEnterInInvalidEmailForField()` which is supposed to return `void`.

You are passing in `string emailType` but never use it.

Comment: So what I want the whenienterininvalidemailforfield() to do is simply type (sendkeys) into the element's text box. All the steps is simply entering in text which is the email address based on the relevant step

Comment: So basically type the relevant text in the relevant field (text box)

Comment: What you are describing is the `GetFieldAndEnterText()` method where you pass in the `By` locator for email or confirmation email field. Why have another method?

Comment: Because in my mind I thought how it works is that I stare in the get field and enter text to say I want to find an element and sendkets to it and in the step definition that will state which element and text based on the step definition. That's why I think looking at it I think the way I'm implementing it is off